# Like box error message for the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I recently tried to generate a like box for my page at http://www.facebook.com/laafalot
The box seems good. But when I click 'like' it says 'Eroor' in red color. Please help me. I used fb's like button generator at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

That's the docs for the Like Button - are you using a Like Button or Like Box? 
What error is displayed? Are you trying to create a Like Button for a page which has demographic restrictions applied? (If so, it may not work properly - a Like Box should work provided the logged in user meets the applied restrictions)